# AWS cdk create new lambda@edge version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-edge

I'm using cdk to add a lambda on edge to a cloudfront web distribution (details see code below).

```
const edgeFunction = new cloudfront.experimental.EdgeFunction(this, 'LambdaOnEdgeAuthFunction', {
   runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
   handler: 'index.handler',
   code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda/auth'),
   description: `Generated on: ${new Date().toISOString()}`
});

// A numbered version to give to cloudfront
const egdeFunctionVersion = new lambda.Version(this, "edgeVersion", {
   lambda: edgeFunction,
   description: `Generated on: ${new Date().toISOString()}`, //adding this did not create new version
});
```

Adding the function to my cloudfront webdistribution

```
// CloudFront distribution that provides HTTPS and used the key pair above
const distribution = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, 'SiteDistribution', {
originConfigs: [{
     s3OriginSource: {
       /* my s3 bucket*/
     },
     behaviors: [{
        isDefaultBehavior: true,
        lambdaFunctionAssociations: [{
          eventType: cloudfront.LambdaEdgeEventType.ORIGIN_REQUEST,
          lambdaFunction: egdeFunctionVersion
          }]
 /*... end of declaration ...*/
```

However, deploying the changes via `cdk deploy --all` always throws the same exception:

> **A version for this Lambda function exists ( 1 ). Modify the function to create a new version.**

I removed all existing lambda function from my account and removed all lambda functions from my existing contributions. But it did not solve the issue. I also applied the fix that is mentioned [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5334) with the same result.

Can you help me with a create a new version or to find and delete the lambda version I have to delete (as said no function does exist in the aws account so far) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to create a new version for lambda@edge is to get the current version of the Function.

```js
const edgeFunc = new lambda.Function(this, 'edgeFuncName', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      handler: 'index.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(edgeFuncPath),
      currentVersionOptions: {
        removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
      }
      
    });
const edgeFuncVersion = edgeFunc.currentVersion
```

Then assign the edgeFuncVersion to CloudFront behaviour

This is described [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/8149)

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda@Edge functions are ONLY deployed in us-east-1 region. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-requirements-cloudfront-triggers)

So you can do 2 things. Try `cdk destroy` and deploy again to see if it fixes the problem.

Alternatively create a new version of lambda function and try again. Reference for version of Lambda function is [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5334)

Verify your Lambda function is in us-east-1 region to verify the root cause of issue.

Comment: I tried to solve this by following the suggestion in GitHub and by creating a new version no success. No lambda function gas been created in any region. In the end Destroy+Deploy fixed it. Here is had to backup my S3 folder before.